# Why can't xlrd library in Python open xlsx file?

Tags: python, xlsx, xlrd

I'm trying to read .xlsx file with Python.
However I noticed that popular library xlrd doesn't work with .xlsx files.
Here is the example with error message I'm getting:

```
import xlrd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loc = ("./excel_file.xlsx")
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
```

I'm getting the following error message while trying to run the code above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/projects/excel_processing_example/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
  File "/Users/username/projects/excel_processing_example/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 170, in open_workbook
    raise XLRDError(FILE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTIONS[file_format]+'; not supported')
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported
```

Is there a reason why xlsx files are not supported by the xlrd library?

Comment: I’m voting to close this because a question about why a library doesn't do something _its documentation explicitly says is outside of its scope_ is off-topic here. (It asks us to intuit the minds of its developers, or look up publicly available mailing list discussions; the former is opinion or guesswork, the latter is an off-site resource request; both are off-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/):

> xlrd is a library for reading data and formatting information from Excel files in the historical `.xls` format.

The choice was made in 2020 to just focus on the `.xls` format, as they didn't want to replicate the work being done by the excellent [`openpyxl`](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/) project.

Answer (score 0):

The support was removed in version 2.0.0 (Dec. 2020), see https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#id1

> Remove support for anything other than .xls files.

Answer (score 0):

XLSX format is an XML format inherited from [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) while XLS is [proprietary format of Microsoft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#File_formats).

Therefore parsing `.xls` file is totally different from parsing `.xlsx`.

If you want to read `xlsx` file, you can use [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)